# Grails x86/x64?

Tags: grails, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I was planning to use Eclipse Juno instead of GGTS/STS provided by SpringSource. I have installed on my Eclipse the plug-in for the GGTS support. I also have downloaded the newest version of Grails that is version 2.3.3. All is well, but when I create a Grails project on my Eclipse IDE this error always occurs on the Console View.

> General error during semantic analysis: unable to locate the java compiler com.sun.tools.javac.Main, please change your classloader settings
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: unable to locate the java compiler com.sun.tools.javac.Main, please change your classloader settings

I don't see any problems when I type `java` on my command prompt. I am currently using Windows 7 x64 with a JavaSE 6/7 both on x64. Is it possible the cause of this problem is that Grails needs to have a jre6+ under x86 platform?

Comment: I can tell you with certainty Grails has no qualms with using an x64 JDK.

Comment: So even if I install a x86 jre6/7, the same error may possible prompt for Eclipse IDE is running on x64?

Comment: Do you have a JRE or a JDK?  Also, what plugins have you installed into your Eclipse?  Even if you don't want to use GGTS, you still need to install Grails-IDE and groovy-eclipse into your Eclipse.

Comment: com.sun.tools.javac.Main is in tools.jar, which is in JDK, NOT JRE. Are you sure you have JDK install and JAVA_HOME set appropriately?

Comment: I have both JRE and JDK of version 6 and 7 on the x64 platform. I recently installed a JDK 7 x32 platform to be sure that the `grails` command using the command prompt (CP) works. After then I can use the `grails` command on CP but the same error still occurs upon creation of project on Eclipse IDE. As per the GGTS plugin. I've installed this update site for the GGTS and STS support `http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.2/`.